# Echad Veshiv'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred seventy-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Rashbam (cited in Tosafos to Avodah Zarah 9b, s.v. האי מאן), the second Beis Hamikdash was destroyed 171 years before the end of the fourth millennium (3829 since Creation).

Answer (score 1):

> 1654-1825 (171 years) The first Jewish
>   settlers, 23 in all, came to New
>   Amsterdam, New York.  Throughout this
>   long period the numbers were small and
>   assimilation was most common.  By the
>   time of the American Revolution there
>   were Jews in all 13 colonies.  They
>   were mostly Sephardic and German Jews
>   totaling only 1,500 by 1790.

http://www.ajzenberg.com/Book/118.htm

Comment: Related to this: during those 171 years there were only Sephardic shuls in America. The first Ashkenazic congregation (Bnei Jeschurun, in New York) was founded in 1825.